# ifstream skipping whole lines

Tags: c++, ifstream

why is this skipping every other line of text in the file starting with the first one? its writing everything in the proper order just skipping half of it

```
    while (getline(inFS, line)) {
        getline(inFS, line);
        if (!inFS.fail()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i += 1) {

                char outChar = CaesarEncode(line[i], 3);

                outFS << outChar;

            }
            outFS << endl;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thats cos you call getline twice each loop, take out the second one

Comment: @pm100 omg thank you i must be real tired

Comment: @TarynBevington you can also take out `if (!inFS.fail())` since `while (getline(inFS, line))` will be false if a failure occurs.